# how to run python in gedit?

Tags: command-line, gedit

I wrote python code in gedit.
As we know there is an internal python console in gedit, how can I run my python code there instead of running it in terminal.

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved by following these steps:

1. Go to the menu and select the **Preferences** option.
2. Go to **Plugins** tab, check the **External Tools** plugin and close the **Preferences** dialog.
3. Go back to the menu and select the **Manage External Tools...** option.

[image]

4. Add a tool and name it **Run** (or anything else you prefer)
5. Insert following code in the right side top section:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    
    import sys
    
    exec(sys.stdin.read())
```

[image]

6. Set following options in the right side bottom section:

- **Shortcut key:** `Ctrl+R` (or any other shortcut you prefer)
- **Save:** `Nothing` (or any of the options you prefer)
- **Input:** `Current document`
- **Output:** `Display in bottom pane`
- **Applicability:** `All documents` `All languages`

7. Close the **Manage External Tools...** dialog.
8. Now you can write any Python code in an open document and press the shortcut key (you set in step 6) to run the code. The code will run whether the document is untitled or saved (whether with `.py` or any other extension).

[image]

9. You might want to set the document type to `Python` to see proper code highlighting for an unsaved document or a file with extension other than `.py`. For a `.py` file this option will be set automatically.

Comment: Amazing answer. Exactly what I wanted. Adding a few extra steps I took to make things look & feel even better.

Comment: Amazing, didn't know gedit can do that. I usually use Visual Studio Code for Python development, it works quite well.

Answer (score 2):

1. Activate the plugin: Preferences/Plugins and check `Python command line` (or something similar, this is my translation)
2. Under View, check Bottom panel.

Comment: I did same, but my problem is how can I execute my python code in the bottom view rather than switching to terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't run anything that you've written in gedit.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make the file run on python without saving and closing it, at first. Then it would run python only after I opened it with `ex gedit filename.py`

Tks again for your tutorial

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1291213)